# MingW C++ Documentation?

Tags: c++, mingw

I remember some years ago, when I learned C using Turbo C, it had a extensive documentation on its headers...

My question is: There are something like that for MingW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinGW is just a windows port of GCC, so the official GCC documentation should work (mostly) just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are MinGW-specific headers - I mean Windows-specific headers. But I'm also searching for a documentation, I couldn't find one yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `man` pages, if you've installed them.

Answer (score 0):

You mean MinGW-specific headers? Do they exist at all? Just look for standard C and/or C++ references. They're all over the web. Look for gcc info, as MinGW is a Windows port of it.